# Entity Framework: Inserting new entity associated with another entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite, linq-to-entities

I have two tables FilesystemEntries and CacheEntries where there is an association of 0..1 CacheEntry per FilesystemEntry (that is a FilesystemEntry can have a null CacheEntry, but not vice-versa). Initially, the CacheEntry for all FilesystemEntries is null. I'm having trouble changing this (adding a new CacheEntry). The code (truncated) looks like this:

```
FilesystemEntry filesystemEntry; // Already exists in database
CacheEntry cacheEntry;           // A new one is created
// ...
filesystemEntry.CacheEntry = cacheEntry;       // Was null before (verified in debugger)
cacheEntry.FilesystemEntry = filesystemEntry;
_db.AddToCacheEntries(cacheEntry);
```

However, I'm recieving the following error:

```
System.Data.UpdateException: A relationship is being added or deleted from an 
AssociationSet 'FK_CacheEntries_0'. With cardinality constraints, a corresponding 
'CacheEntries' must also be added or deleted.
```

Any entity framework wizards know what's going on?

Similarly, is there any way to allow the database to handle the "ON DELETE CASCADE" (I'm using sqlite, so it'll be via a trigger)? This would be a lot more convenient and future-proof than specifying all the deletes in the DAL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the problem.

But I'd try doing this:

```
FilesystemEntry filesystemEntry; // Already exists in database
CacheEntry cacheEntry;   // A new one is created        
filesystemEntry.CacheEntry = cacheEntry; 
// redundant cacheEntry.FilesystemEntry = filesystemEntry;
// redundant _db.AddToCacheEntries(cacheEntry);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

The first redundant operation might be causing the problem.

As for cascade delete take a look at this [Tip](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/08/19/tip-33-how-cascade-delete-really-works-in-ef.aspx) for an explanation of how Cascade delete *really* works in EF.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but unless I'm misunderstanding your entity relationships, you might try it without the

```
cacheEntry.FilesystemEntry = filesystemEntry;
```

line. This should be implicit by the fact that you set

```
filesystemEntry.CacheEntry = cacheEntry;
```

Also I've had good luck using the following type of assignment when dealing with navigation properties:

```
cacheEntry.FilesystemEntryReference.Value = filesystemEntry;
```